# onBindViewHolder not called when use data binding on RecyclerView

Tags: android, mvvm, data-binding, android-recyclerview, android-livedata

onBindViewHolder not called when use data binding on Recyclerview.
So, the Activity show blank white screen.

When I see on logcat, the list size and itemCount is 20 but onBindViewHolder method never called.

```java
class NewsAdapter : RecyclerView.Adapter<NewsAdapter.ViewHolder>() {

    private val listArticle = mutableListOf<Article>()

    fun update(list: List<Article>) {
        listArticle.addAll(list)
        notifyDataSetChanged()
    }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(viewGroup: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): NewsAdapter.ViewHolder {
        return ViewHolder(viewGroup)
    }

    class ViewHolder(
            private val parent: ViewGroup,
            private val binding: AdapterNewsBinding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(
                    LayoutInflater.from(parent.context),
                    R.layout.adapter_news,
                    parent,
                    false
            )
    ) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(binding.root) {
        fun bind(article: Article) {
            binding.article = article
        }
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(viewHolder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        Log.d("NewsAdapter", "onBindViewHolder")
        viewHolder.bind(listArticle[position])
    }

    override fun getItemCount() = listArticle.size
}
```

How to call onBindViewHolder in Recyclerview with data binding?
So I can show the data on Activity.

Answer (score 0):

Solved

1. add apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt' in your app gradle
2. So, you can make static method like this on your adapter

```java
companion object {
        @BindingAdapter("items")
        @JvmStatic
        fun RecyclerView.bindItems(items: List<Article>?) {
            val adapter = adapter as NewsAdapter
            if (!items.isNullOrEmpty()) adapter.update(items)
        }
    }
```

Done